# Column values to columns with ID

Tags: python, dictionary, datatables, multiple-columns

Given a dataframe table like so with given values I would like to convert it to another table and dictionary.

convert this:

```
id    type
a     x
a     y
a     y
b     z
```

to this:

```
id  x   y   z
a   1   2   0
b   0   0   1
```

in a table format and a dictionary.

```
dict = {{a:{x:1, y:2, z:0}},{b:{x:1,y:2,z:0}}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the format of that "table"?  What have you tried so far?  You *can* do this with a one-liner (not necessarily the most readable way), using nested dictionary comprehensions and the `count` method.  Is that enough of a hint?

Comment: sorry I should've specified. The table is a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you load your table as a list of tuples, use `collections.Counter` to count the number of occurrences of each tuple, then transform it into the dict output you want while keep tracking of the unique types in a set, and finally fill in the missing type keys in each id with zeroes in the dict.

```
from collections import Counter
l = [('a', 'x'), ('a', 'y'), ('a', 'y'), ('b', 'z')]
d = {}
k = set()
for t, c in Counter(l).items():
    d.setdefault(t[0], {})[t[1]] = c
    k.add(t[1])
for v in d.values():
    for m in k.difference(v):
        v.update({m: 0})
print(d)
```

This outputs:

```
{'a': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 0}, 'b': {'z': 1, 'x': 0, 'y': 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('id'), 
               columns=['type'], 
               prefix='', prefix_sep='')\
  .sum(level=0)\
  .to_dict(orient='index')
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 0}, 'b': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 1}}
```